# How to connect Zeppelin to a database that is through an ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, apache-zeppelin

I have a local zeppelin instance running on my mac at localhost:8080 and I am trying to connect to a postgres database that is remote. I can access it via ssh and have set up a key pair for my computer but I can't figure out how to have zeppelin query the db directly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Zeppelin currently support database connection via ssh.

But you can still use a ssh tunnel and connect to your database.

1/ Start a tunnel by running this in a console :

```
ssh -i PATH_TO_KEY -L 5432:localhost:5432 USER@HOST -N
```

Where USER is the username associated the key pair and HOST is the ip address of your postgres host

2/ Create the zeppelin interpreter as if postgres was running locally

(this means default.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ )